# Proving existence of sequence based on a limit of a function of it

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I'm interested in proving the following claim:

There exists a sequence of natural numbers $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)^{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

I've studied a fair amount of calculus and algebra, yet I've never encountered such a problem before.
How should I approach this claim, or rather what tools should I read about?

Thanks!

Comment: The notation's a little screwy: your sequence isn't really a subset of the naturals; it's just a sequence where every item in the sequence is a natural number. But since a sequence is not a set, it doesn't really make sense to use the term "subset" on it.

Comment: Your'e absolutely right. It's an abuse of notation which I thought was common / acceptable, but I guess I was wrong. I'll edit the post immediately.

Comment: @Spencer I misread it, thanks.

Comment: I suspect that particular abuse of notation is pretty common and probably *is* widely acceptable; I just happen not to like it. :) (Probably comes from my having gradually become a computer science person, and finding math's love of notational 'puns' a nightmare for students who have to actually implement things.)

Comment: Of course when stating a mathematical claim to complete strangers on the internet it's best to just use words, but when writing on the blackboard, what do you use? Perhaps $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}\in^{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N}$? Or simply $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\quad a_{n}\in\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\ln 2$ as a binary number with bits $b_1, b_2, \ldots$.

As others have suggested in briefly-present answers, taking logs is the secret: you want 
 $$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_n}{2^n}=\ln(2)
$$

and hence
 $$a_n=2^n\ln(2).$$
but this choice of $a_n$ is not an integer. On the other hand, the 
floor of it is. So we pick

$$a_n=\lfloor 2^n\ln(2) \rfloor$$

which is just the binary "whole number" whose bits (before the decimal point, so to speak) are $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$.

Then the question becomes why the limit in this case is the same as in the case without the floors.

Letting 
$$q_n=2^n\ln(2),$$ 
I'm claiming that 
$$
\lim \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)^{a_{n}}=\lim \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)^{q_{n}}.
$$

Taking log of both sides, this is the same as 
$$
\lim a_n \log \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)= \lim q_n \log\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)^{q_{n}}
$$
or 
$$
\lim (a_n-q_n) \log \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)= 0.
$$
Now $a_n - q_n$ is between 0 and 1, and $\log \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right) \approx -\frac{1}{2^{n}}$, so it's clear that the limit is bounded below by  $$-2\frac{1}{2^{n}},$$ which goes to 0, so the squeeze lemma applies and the limit is indeed 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try

$$a_n=\lfloor2^n\ln2\rfloor$$

and use the inequalities $2^n\ln2-1\lt a_n\le2^n\ln2$ in the Squeeze Theorem:  Since $1-{1\over2^n}\lt1$, we have

$$\left(1-{1\over2^n}\right)^{2^n\ln2}\le\left(1-{1\over2^n}\right)^{a_n}\lt\left(1-{1\over2^n}\right)^{2^n\ln2-1}$$

The left- and right-hand expressions are easily seen to tend to $(e^{-1})^{\ln2}={1\over e^{\ln2}}={1\over2}$ as $n\to\infty$.